# Open a new component when the register button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, components

Open as a new page and the user goes inside the page when the button is clicked. How can I do it in react functional component? I want to navigate from `Register` to another `MyProfile` component when button is clicked. The code for `Register` component is as below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Register.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
   
function Register() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmpassword: "",
});

const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
            history.push("/myprofile")
}

const InputEvent = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setData((preVal) => {
        return {
            ...preVal,
            [name]: value,
        };
    });
};

     const formSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
     };

    return (
        <div className="signup__container">

            <div className="signup__containerInfo">
            <h1 className="h1__swari">swari</h1>
            <hr />
            </div>


<form4 onSubmit={formSubmit}>
<h5 className="h5__form"> Name</h5>
<input type="text" placeholder="Full Name"  name="name" value={data.name} onChange={InputEvent} />
<h5 className="h5__form"> Email-Address </h5>
<input type="Email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value={data.email} onChange={InputEvent} />
<h5 className="h5__form"> Password </h5>
<input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value={data.password} onChange={InputEvent} />
<h5 className="h5__form"> Confirm Password </h5>
<input type="Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" value={data.confirmpassword} onChange={InputEvent} />
<p>
<button onClick={register} type="submit" className="signup__registerButton" >Register Now</button>
</p>
</form4>
        </div>
    )
    }

export default Register
```

Comment: Are you using any routing frameworks like [React Router: Declarative Routing for React.js](https://reactrouter.com/)? We need something like that to achieve what you're expecting. It's very simple to implement too.

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar Purushothaman yes i using react router -routing framework for routing, but for now i only want to route from the register component to MyProfile component when the register button is clicked.

Comment: You could have done `<Link to="/Register">Button</Link>` and use `<Route path="/Register" component={Register} />`? Does that not work?

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar Purushothaman will it work? can u be  specific to where to put the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate component of History.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then in Register component.

```
 import history from "../Shared/history";
    
 const formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
     history.push("/SomeComponent", {
                  someData: true,
                  otherData:{},
                });
  };
```

In Routes:

```
  <Route path="/SomeComponent" component={Component} />
```

Comment: Ehsan Gondal it doesnt work bro when i click on register now button it doesnt happen anything.

Comment: please share any error, check console errors in dev tools.

Comment: Ehsan Gondal i have updated the code pls check. also plus when i click on the button it routes to 'http://localhost:3000/MyProfile' but doesnot loads the new page it stays on the same page.